# different outcomes when selecting objects from a "box"?

Tags: probability

> ${\bf 1.}$ Suppose that 10 fish are caught at a lake that contains 5
> distinct types of fish.
>
> ${\bf a)}$ How many different outcomes are possible, where an outcome
> specifies the numbers of caught fish of each of the 5 types?
>
> ${\bf b)}$ How many are possible when $3$ out of the 10 fish caught
> are trout?
>
> ${\bf c)}$How many when at least $2$ of the $10$ are trout?

#### Try:

Since we are not given how many of each there is, then can just let $n_i$ be the number of type i of fish so that $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5 = 10$. Therefore, for a), we have

$$ \frac{10!}{n_1! n_2! n_3! n_4! n_5 ! } $$

and for b), now we know that 3 of them are trout, but we still have no information about the other types thus can do same as before, $n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=7$ and so total outcomes now is

$$ \frac{10!}{3! n_2! n_3! n_4! n_5!} $$

for part c), Im kind of confused, any hints? hows my work so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since given that $10$ fish are caught from the lake that contains $5$ distinct types of fish which means that the lake contains of $5$ distinct fish and not $10$ fish contain $5$ distinct fish.

For part $a)$

The different outcomes possible when fish of $5$ types caught are $\dbinom{10+5-1}{5-1}=\dbinom{14}{4}=1001$

For part $b)$

The number of outcomes possible when $3$ out of the $10$ fish caught are $\dbinom{7+4-1}{4-1}=\dbinom{10}{3}=120$

For part $c)$

When there is only $1$ trout then $\dbinom{9+4-1}{4-1}=220$

When there are $0$ trout then $\dbinom{10+4-1}{4-1}=286$

When there are at least $2$ out of $10$ trout are $1001-220-286=495$

Comment: Im very confused as to how this is true? Did I misundertood the problem?

Comment: @Neymar See the edited answer